# Not understanding pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have following C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *p, *q;
    *p=5;
    *q=6;
    printf("%d %d", *p, *q);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is not running. Whats wrong with this code??

Comment: For future reference, rather than "The code is not running", tell us exactly how it fails. If there's an error message, copy-and-paste it into your question. The problem was straightforward enough in this case, but next time it may not be.

Comment: The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is an excellent resource. Section 4 covers pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointer are not initialized, they need to point to valid memory using malloc or by taking address of a local variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int p, q;
    int *pp = &p;
    int *pq = &q;
    *pp=5;
    *pq=6;
    printf("%d %d", *pp, *pq);
    return 0;
}
```

would work.

Comment: How can I initialize them?

Comment: Edited my answer. Only shown the local variable though as I can't see why you would use new for this case.

Comment: That's what they are used for yes.

Comment: What is `new`? (Hint: The question is tagged C, not C++.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, changed to malloc.